# Flutter : A value of type 'List<Type>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Type>'

Tags: flutter

I want to fetch and print datas from this json file :

```
[{"id": "76d751584e134ebf854bebda8998334b", "data": {"timestamp": "15/05/2021-13:08:38", "temperature": 21.9, "pressure": 1007.4342535, "humidity": 43.994442131}}, {"id": "6188e169eeda4547b3e87414d50664df", "data": {"timestamp": "15/05/2021-15:08:38", "temperature": 22.28, "pressure": 1006.47539066, "humidity": 46.1434366089}}, {"id": "4eb75a12fd6c4eb8a94b20106aab4e2a", "data": {"timestamp": "15/05/2021-17:08:38", "temperature": 22.71, "pressure": 1006.52941164, "humidity": 47.7676641555}}]
```

This is my flutter code witch is supposed to do the job :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SensorData with ChangeNotifier {
  //final id;
  final timestamp;
  final temperature;
  final pressure;
  final humidity;

  SensorData({
    //@required this.id,
    @required this.timestamp,
    @required this.temperature,
    @required this.pressure,
    @required this.humidity,
  });

  factory SensorData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new SensorData(
      //id: json['id'] as String,
      timestamp: json['timestamp'] as String,
      temperature: json['temperature'] as double,
      pressure: json['pressure'] as double,
      humidity: json['humidity'] as double,
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  Future<List<SensorData>> fetchSensorDatas() async {
    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.http(<my_API_url>));
      var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      return (responseJson['data'] as List)
          .map((p) => SensorData.fromJson(p))
          .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Container(
              height: 200,
            ),
            new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new FutureBuilder<List<SensorData>>(
                  future: fetchSensorDatas(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData){
                      List<SensorData> posts = snapshot.data;
                      return new Column(
                          children: posts.map((post) => new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text(post.temperature),
                            ],
                          )).toList()
                      );
                    }
                    else if(snapshot.hasError)
                    {
                      return snapshot.error;
                    }
                    return new Center(
                      child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(50.0)),
                          new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have 2 errors :

- snapshot.data returns me "A value of type 'List?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'."
- snapshot.error returns me "The return type 'Object?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.".

Where am I getting wrong?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have never used Flutter and don't know much about it, but going by some assumptions here, it may be the case that you are trying to assign a value of a nullable type to a reference of a non-nullable type, which Dart is explicitly designed to prevent: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: (1) Inside `if (snapshot.hasData)` add postfix operator to snapshot.data to `snapshot.data!`

Comment: (2) Inside `if(snapshot.hasError)` just return widget like `Text`, ex: `Text(snapshot.error.toString())`, because `FutureBuilder` need a return `Widget`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> snapshot.data returns me "A value of type 'List?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'."

The problem is inside the `fetchSensorDatas` method. Since `responseJson` is a `Map`, every time you access a key from it, there is a possibility that this key does not exist and it'll return null (therefore returning the nullable type `List?`). If you are sure that the key exists, you can do the following:

```
final List data = responseJson['data']! as List;
return data.map((p) => SensorData.fromJson(p)).toList();
```

> snapshot.error returns me "The return type 'Object?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.".

That's because you're returning multiple types inside the `builder` parameter of `FutureBuilder`, and therefore the return type of it will be the common ascestor of all types being returned, which in this case is `Object`. Note that you're returning a `Column` in the first condition, an `Error` in the second condition and a `Center` in the third condition. You can replace the second return with some `Wigdet`:

```dart
else if (snapshot.hasError){
  // Alternative 1: return a Text widget with the error message
  return Text(snapshot.error?.toString() ?? "");
  
  // Alternative 2: print the error message and return an empty widget
  print(snapshot.error);
  return SizedBox.shrink();

  // Alternative 3: display the user that an error has occurred with a descriptive widget
  return Text("An error has occured.");

  // Alternative 4: rethrow the error
  throw snapshot.error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Unfortunately I still have the error about the fetchSensorDatas method...

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!

First of all my model was very poor, so I rewrote it like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<SensorData> sensorDataFromJson(String str) => List<SensorData>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => SensorData.fromJson(x)));

String sensorDataToJson(List<SensorData> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class SensorData {
    SensorData({
        required this.id,
        required this.data,
    });

    String id;
    Data data;

    factory SensorData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SensorData(
        id: json["id"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "data": data.toJson(),
    };
}

class Data {
    Data({
        required this.timestamp,
        required this.temperature,
        required this.pressure,
        required this.humidity,
    });

    String timestamp;
    double temperature;
    double pressure;
    double humidity;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        timestamp: json["timestamp"],
        temperature: json["temperature"].toDouble(),
        pressure: json["pressure"].toDouble(),
        humidity: json["humidity"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "temperature": temperature,
        "pressure": pressure,
        "humidity": humidity,
    };
}
```

Then I have a method returning the get request :

```
Future<List<SensorData>> getSensorDatas() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.http('192.168.1.3:5000', '/pigarden/'));
    return sensorDataFromJson(response.body);
}
```

And finally my app file looks like this :

```
FutureBuilder<List<SensorData>>(
        future: SensorDatasRepository().getSensorDatas(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder : (BuildContext context) => const AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Error"),
                content: Text('An error has occured...'),
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data![index].id),
                subtitle: Text(
                  snapshot.data![index].data.temperature.toString(),
                  softWrap: false,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
```

And now it works just fine!